# ImageView Segue to SplitView

Tags: uisplitviewcontroller, ipad, ios5

I'm trying to implement this example [Basic Security in iOS 5](http://www.raywenderlich.com/6475/basic-security-in-ios-5-tutorial-part-1), but instead of performing the segue to a tableView I'm trying to make the segue to a splitViewController. When it tries to make the segue it throws this error if I use replace:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not find a split view controller ancestor for '', while performing a split view controller replace segue (identifier 'LoginSegue') with destination '''

and if I use modal (like in the tutorial):

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Application tried to present a Split View Controllers modally .'

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi i Found the way to solve this problem here is the link, it's in japanese just translate it [cheesememo.blog39.fc2.com/blog-entry-465.html](http://cheesememo.blog39.fc2.com/blog-entry-465.html)

Answer (score 1):

Did you find a fix for this? ... THe splitview controller needs to be the root view controller of the application. You can't transition from a normal view to a splitview controller

Comment: no i didnt find the answer, what i do was put the splashimage  and hide the tableview until the user is logged in

Answer (score 0):

I've been able to segue to a split view controller by embedding it in a navigation controller at segueing to it modally in a storyboard.